# What's different between these two row conversion functions?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I found an example from https://bl.ocks.org/. The example uses `d3.csv` to import the data. But I don't want to use `d3.csv` to import the external file, I just want to use the data that exists in the current environment, so I customized my own conversion function.

Original code:

```
d3.csv("data.csv",
function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
},
function (data){
...
})
...
```

My attempt:

```
var tmp_data = type(data);
dataViz(tmp_data);

function type(data) {
  data.columns = Object.keys(data[0]);
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < data.columns.length; ++i) t += data[data.columns[i]] = +data[data.columns[i]];
  data.total = t;
  return data;
};

function dataViz(data){
...
};
```

After input my data into `type` function, `data.total` is `NaN`. I can't understand how `t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]]` works and what it looks like in `data.total` in the `d3.csv` method. How could I fix my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original data in the bl.ocks that you used as example ([this one](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3886208), your link is broken) looks like this:

```
State,Under 5 Years,5 to 13 Years,14 to 17 Years,18 to 24 Years,25 to 44 Years,45 to 64 Years,65 Years and Over
AL,310504,552339,259034,450818,1231572,1215966,641667
AK,52083,85640,42153,74257,198724,183159,50277
AZ,515910,828669,362642,601943,1804762,1523681,862573
AR,202070,343207,157204,264160,754420,727124,407205
CA,2704659,4499890,2159981,3853788,10604510,8819342,4114496
```

So, let's see how we can replicate that row function:

The main problem with your attempt is that, unlike the original row function, you're not iterating through **each object** in the data array. When you do this...

```
data.total = t;
```

... you're just setting a property in that array, which is not what you want.

So, you have to iterate through each object in the array. For instance, using `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
function type(data) {
  data.columns = Object.keys(data[0]);
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    for (i = 1, t = 0; i < data.columns.length; ++i) t += d[data.columns[i]] = +d[data.columns[i]];
    d.total = t;
  });
  return data;
};
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var csv = `State,Under 5 Years,5 to 13 Years,14 to 17 Years,18 to 24 Years,25 to 44 Years,45 to 64 Years,65 Years and Over
AL,310504,552339,259034,450818,1231572,1215966,641667
AK,52083,85640,42153,74257,198724,183159,50277
AZ,515910,828669,362642,601943,1804762,1523681,862573
AR,202070,343207,157204,264160,754420,727124,407205
CA,2704659,4499890,2159981,3853788,10604510,8819342,4114496`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv);

var tmp_data = type(data);

console.log(tmp_data)

function type(data) {
  data.columns = Object.keys(data[0]);
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    for (i = 1, t = 0; i < data.columns.length; ++i) t += d[data.columns[i]] = +d[data.columns[i]];
    d.total = t;
  });
  return data;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```